# Regex for pulling in-text citations from pull citations using R

Tags: r, regex

I'm using R and would like to create an in-text from a full citation using regex. For instance, I have:

```
Ali, D. A., Deininger, K., & Goldstein, M. (2014). Environmental and gender 
impacts of land tenure regularization in Africa: Pilot evidence from Rwanda. 
Journal of Development Economics, 110, 262–275.
```

I would like a regex that pulls all information up to the first 4-digit number, including the parathesis. Like this:

```
Ali, D. A., Deininger, K., & Goldstein, M. (2014)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I do not see the question replicated. Could you point it out and I will make the necessary edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("^(.*\\(\\d{4}\\)).*", "\\1", txt)
#[1] "Ali, D. A., Deininger, K., & Goldstein, M. (2014)"
```

---

Or another approach would be to get the index of the first match where the 4-digit number occurs and then do a `substr`

```
i1 <- regexpr("(?<=\\()\\d{4}(?=\\))", txt, perl = TRUE)
substr(txt, seq(i1), i1+ attr(i1, "match.length"))
#[1] "Ali, D. A., Deininger, K., & Goldstein, M. (2014)"
```

Comment: This `[^(]` is not a good idea, akrun. What if there is a `(` before the first (4 digits) ?.

Comment: Now, `"^(.*\\(\\d{4}\\)).*"` will match the *last* occurrence of (4digits) and `"\\d{4}"` does not really match (4digits) but just 4digits. It seems you are overcomplicating the solution, especially the one with `sub`.

Comment: if you are talking about the second solution, I think i didn't made it specific.  corrected